# Item Option (Parameter / Switch) in Backup-SPFarm & Restore SP-Farm for Multi-Tenant SharePoint 2013 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, backup, restore, multi-tenancy

I have a SharePoint 2013 Multi-Tenant Farm. Every tenant has a dedicated Content DB. I am trying to backup a particular Tenant using the following command, found in the [Understanding multi-tenancy in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659286.aspx). But, in that, I am not sure about the Item option.

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory "c:\backups\alpha" -Item "HostingFarm_Content_Hosting" -BackupMethod Full
```

Also, while restoring, I am not sure, what to provide for the Item parameter in the following command. Also, the article above doesn't mention, whether this restore will work like a DB restore, wherein, the restore can be done even w/o creating a DB or we need to create a tenant first to be able to restore by overwriting it. Can anyone please explain?

```
Restore-SPFarm -Directory "c:\backups\alpha" -Item "HostingFarm_Content_Hosting" -RestoreMethod Overwrite
```